# Android JNI debugging takes forever

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am using Eclipse + gdbserver + ndk7. It seems that debugging through native code (called  by Java ) takes ages to step through (~20sec each step), What might cause that? is this  normal behaviour?

Comment: Are you using emulator for debugging? I've noticed huge delays when I use gdb with emulator. Debugging app on device had no such delays.

Answer (score 0):

You can use logging for debugging. please look at this [link](http://vitobrothersoft.com/2011/06/17/how-to-start-logging-for-android-ndk/).

- Include log.h file into your Android NDK source file

  ```
   #include <android/log.h>
  ```
- Add the line below to your Android.mk make file.

  ```
   LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
  ```

Now you can start logging, this two steps allows you to write logs in Eclipse from Android NDK. Write the line below in your Android NDK code and the log will bw appear in the Eclipse

```
     __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR,"Tag","Message");
```

use following Flags to write logs in the column which you want.

```
typedef enum android_LogPriority {
    ANDROID_LOG_UNKNOWN = 0,
    ANDROID_LOG_DEFAULT,    /* only for SetMinPriority() */
    ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE,
    ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG,
    ANDROID_LOG_INFO,
    ANDROID_LOG_WARN,
    ANDROID_LOG_ERROR,
    ANDROID_LOG_FATAL,
    ANDROID_LOG_SILENT,     /* only for SetMinPriority(); must be last */
} android_LogPriority
```

For example if you want to write in Info column you must write

```
     __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,"Tag","Message");
```

Comment: Well, debugging with logs is not that efficient... I really need to be able to step through with the debugger to be able to make a good use of my time...